# How can I retrieve contents from a URL when I click on a link using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
   <div class="button accessLink"
      id="loginLink"
      data-href="/User/Account/Login"
      title="Login">Login</div>
```

What I need to do is when the user clicks on the div then I 
want to call the URL "/User/Account/Login" and then get the 
contents. I have the following code but I am not sure. Do I 
need to use Ajax and if so how can I code it to call the URL.

```
   $('#loginLink')
      .click(function () {

      return false;
      });
```

I want to take the contents and place these inside this HTML:

```
<article id="article" class="container_12">
</article>
```

Any advice on how I can do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use jQuary 'Load' function [here is a link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get the href and [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the content :

```
 $('#loginLink').click(function () {
     $('#article').load($(this).data('href'));
     return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery 'Load' function  [here is a link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's located on the same origin, you can use jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('#loginLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#article').load('/User/Account/Login');
});
```